# How do I get dynamic query text from a URL?

Tags: java, maven, selenium

How can I get the value "2" of "entityId=2" from this example Url: https://test.com/form/form.htm?Index=0&entityId=2&wid=74&_wid=74 using Java and assuming this value is not static?

I am using:

```
URL url = new URL("https://test.com/form/form.htm?Index=0&entityId=2&wid=74&_wid=74");
String quesries = url.getQuery();
int i = quesries.length();`enter code here`
System.out.println(i);
```

Which gave me length of 33.

Comment: Is that url "https://test.com/form/form.htm?Index=0&entityId=2&wid=74&_wid=74" is a string, from which you want to extract the entityId?

Comment: @supputuri No that is Url not string

Comment: Sorry, not sure about the ask here. Do you want to extract part of the text from the url?

Comment: Yes, i want to extract the value of "entityId" parameter which is "2" and also dynamic, that means if I will open this url again this value "2" will change to something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to use the `substring` method in Java.

```
String entityId = urlString.substring(urlString.indexOf("entityId=")+9,urlString.indexOf("&wid"))
```

[image]